# Make bazel use local copy of a pip package if available

Tags: pip, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-python

How can I make Bazel use a local pip package (if it's already available on the system and matches the version requirement). If the package is not available locally, I want Bazel to download and install it in the sandbox.

Ideally, I want this all abstracted in a simple rule that I can add as dependency to my `py_library` or `py_binary` rules.

Context: I am using Bazel for developing some python libraries. I have several separate projects, all of which depend on pytorch, which is 4GB in size. With 4 separate projects, this is a lot of space to install 4 times in separate sandboxes. My target platform is Linux.

Comment: Feels kind of related to this question from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77766337 -- Maybe the conda ecosystem is your best bet.